# In $\mathbb{R}^n$, what is $B(p, ε) + \{b\}?$

Tags: metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, suppose $A$ is an open set and $B$ is any set. Show that the set
$A + B = \{a + b : a ∈ A, b ∈ B\}$ is open.

For the solution i'm stuck at this point: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, what is $B(p, ε) + \{b\}?$

Comment: $B(p+b,\epsilon).$

Comment: Tacking onto @ThomasAndrews's comment: To see it, that is exactly $B(p, \varepsilon) + \{b\} = \{a+b : a \in B(p, \varepsilon)\}$. I.e., you've translated the ball over by $b$.

Comment: @BrianTung so its just an open ball with center $p+b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is said in the comments, it is just the open ball around $b+p$ and radius $\varepsilon$:
$$\begin{align*}
B(p,\varepsilon) + \{b\} 
&= \{a+b : a \in B(p,\varepsilon)\} \\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R^n : \exists a \in B(p,\varepsilon),\, x=a+b\} \\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R^n : \exists a \in B(p,\varepsilon),\, x-b=a\} \\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R^n : x-b \in B(p,\varepsilon)\} \\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R^n : \|(x-b)-p\|<\varepsilon\} \\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R^n : \|x-(b+p)\|<\varepsilon\} \\
&= B(b+p,\varepsilon).
\end{align*}$$